# Removing [External] Tag in Email Subject, Unable to Sort by Subject After

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a macro I wrote (with help from this site!) which searches my Inbox and removes [External] tags from email Subjects.  When I run it, it seems to be working as I can see that it removes the tags in real time.  I'll then reply to the email and bcc myself.  The problem is that when I sort by Subject, Outlook separates all of my bcc emails from the external emails, as though their Subjects are not the same (even though they look identical in Outlook).

So, I checked the source on a bcc email and an external email that has had the macro run on it.  The bcc email's source shows the Subject as I'd expect with no [External] tag.  The external email's source shows the original email with [External] tag (even though Outlook's GUI shows the Subject to have no [External] tag).  Farther down the bcc email's source shows the email I replied to (the original email) to have [External] in the Subject, as though it was never removed.

It's like the [External] removal only worked on my reply with regards to sorting.  Any ideas on what's happening here?  Why is Outlook showing an altered Subject, but not actually changing the source?  What's the point?

Macro code snippet:

```
If InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "[External] ") > 0 Then
            myitem.Subject = Replace(myitem.Subject, "[External] ", "")
            myitem.Save
```

Outlook GUI view after running macro:

```
FROM                SUBJECT
Me                  RE: Test Email
Original Sender     RE: Test Email
```

Bcc email reply Subject source:

```
<br><b>Subject:</b> RE: Test Email
(Bcc reply email body)
<br><b>Subject:</b> RE: [External] RE: RE: Test Email
(Original email body)
```

Original external email Subject source:

```
<br><b>Subject:</b> RE: [External] RE: RE: Test Email
(Original email body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook sorts/groups on the `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX MAPI` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102`). Try to preserve it - read it (`MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`) before resetting the `Subject` property and set it back (`MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`) afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, @Dmitry for your response.  I tried adding this (code below), but it still doesn't sort by subject properly after running.  For reference, I tested it today.  Before running the code, they sorted fine, but no longer after the code ran.  Did I implement it incorrectly?

`mapiSpot = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102"

convIndex = myitem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(mapiSpot)
myitem.Subject = Replace(myitem.Subject, "[EXTERNAL] ", "", [vbTextCompare])
myitem.Save
myitem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty mapiSpot, convIndex`

Comment: You are setting back the PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX MAPI property *after* calling save. Your change won't persist.

Comment: of course I made an ordering mistake.  I changed it, have done some testing, and it still seems to be breaking the Subject sort.  Any ideas?
`mapiSpot = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102"
convIndex = myitem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(mapiSpot)
            myitem.Subject = Replace(myitem.Subject, "[EXTERNAL] ", "", [vbTextCompare])
            myitem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty mapiSpot, convIndex
            myitem.Save`

Comment: Have you tried to compare the good and the bad messages in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?